# jsoup thread safety

Tags: java, jsoup

Jsoup `parse(String html)` is not ducumented as thread safe. How do you parse multiple documents with Jsoup concurrently? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By using `Joup.parse`.

As long as you're not working on the same document, it creates new object internally.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jsoup/QIij7DEhj8E

This comes up from time to time; it's probably worth filing a documentation issue against this.

Comment: I'd like to point out that it's helpful to confirm this with the source code on github: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/releases for the specific version you have. I'm using 1.7.2 and confirmed it for using Jsoup.clean as thread safe. Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the [Jsoup.java](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/org/jsoup/Jsoup.java?av=f) source code it doesn't have any state and both *parse()* methods are delegating to [Parser.parse()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.java#Parser.parse%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29) that is internally creating and delegating to a [TreeBuilder.parse()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.6.1/org/jsoup/parser/TreeBuilder.java#TreeBuilder.parse%28java.lang.String,java.lang.String%29). Both *Jsoup* and *Parser* classes have no state and are only holding static methods. *TreeBuilder* class though has a state and seems to be doing all the work but it's created from within a method therefore the whole operation is thread-safe by virtue of stack/thread confinement.

Comment: Maybe this was a recent change, but `Parser` definitely has state, e.g. this: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/parser/Parser.html#getErrors%28%29

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the previous answer from empirical evidence: We have used JSoup 1.6.1 with 20 requests per second during a performance test with no adverse results.