# Is jsoup Document thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, jsoup

Is it safe to use jsoup `someDocument.select(..)` from multiple threads or is there some internal state for **read** operations?

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445589/jsoup-thread-safety)?

Comment: Yes, but I call `Jsoup.parse` once and share the result (`jsoup.Document`) over multiple threads. My hope is that read access to the document is thread safe. (I will never write to the resulting `jsoup.Document`/`jsoup.Element`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call safely [`Document.select(String cssSelector)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-) from multiple threads even though [`Document`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html) class is not thread-safe. Underlying implementation of `.select(String cssSelector)` method passes reference to the element that called this method (`Document` object in this case), but it does not call any method that changes state of the caller.

When you call `.select(String cssSelector)` you actually call [`Collector.collect(Evaluator eval, Element root)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Collector.html#collect-org.jsoup.select.Evaluator-org.jsoup.nodes.Element-) method, where `root` instance is a reference to the `Document` object.

```
/**
 Build a list of elements, by visiting root and every descendant of root, and testing it against the evaluator.
 @param eval Evaluator to test elements against
 @param root root of tree to descend
 @return list of matches; empty if none
 */
public static Elements collect (Evaluator eval, Element root) {
    Elements elements = new Elements();
    new NodeTraversor(new Accumulator(root, elements, eval)).traverse(root);
    return elements;
}
```

In this method only `elements` object gets updated.

#### Why `Document` class is not thread-safe?

There are a few methods in `Document` class that allow to change state of the object without any synchronization mechanism, e.g. [`Document.outputSettings(Document.OutputSettings outputSettings)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#outputSettings-org.jsoup.nodes.Document.OutputSettings-). In best case `Document` class should be final and immutable so sharing its instance between multiple threads won't be a problem.

Comment: There's a fix on OutputSettings to make it threadsafe: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/3b2440a257df45fc49884a5c67bb0c9ce631781d