# Jsoup executing concurrently throws UnknownHostException

Tags: java, multithreading, jsoup

I try to run Jsoup (version 1.11.2) in parallel with this code:

```
public class JsoupParallelRunner {

private static String[] urls = { ... some URLs ...}

public static void main(String... args) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    for (String url : urls) {
        executor.execute(() -> {
            try {
                Connection c = Jsoup.connect(url);
                Connection.Response r = c.execute();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But if I use more than 6 parallel threads in the `FixedThreadPool` it throws a `java.net.UnknownHostException` in the `execute()` method of Jsoup. Below 6 there are no problems.

According to [jsoup thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445589/jsoup-thread-safety) Jsoup is thread-safe.

If it is of any help: my CPU has 2 cores (4 virtual).

**Update**: It seems to be an issue of my computer only. I tried it on two other computers (same Java version, same Jsoup version) and there it worked.

**Update 2**: It seems to be an issue of my laptop in a certain network. I tried it with this laptop at my home network - and there it worked. Back to work - same problem. Everything else network related seems to work (Browser, ssh etc.). I guess it is some weird network issue and has nothing to do with Jsoup.

Answer (score 0):

try checking if you have proxy configured at work. If yes then you have to provide proxy for the JSOUP connection

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(<website.com>).proxy(<host>, <port>).get();
```